# How to resize Image on upload using `Multer and Sharp` on Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sharp

I tried to resize my image when it's being uploaded, but I am not succeeding. I am using Node, Expressjs, Mongoose, Multer and Sharp. How do I resize it on upload with Sharp.

Here is my create routes

```
router.post('/create', upload.single('cover'), async (req, res, next) => {
 const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null
 let witdth = 100;
 let height = 100;

 sharp(req.file)
 .resize(witdth, height).toFile(req.file.path)


 const event = new Event({
 startingDate: req.body.startingDate,
 closingDate: req.body.closingDate,
 title: req.body.title,
 description: req.body.description,
 eventImage: fileName 
})
try {    
  const events = await event.save()
  res.redirect("/events")

  } catch {
   if (event.eventImage != null) {
     removeeventImage(event.eventImage)
   }
    res.render("events/new")
 }
});
```

and my uploader path

```
const uploadPath = path.join('public', Event.eventImageBasePath)
const imageMineTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']

const upload = multer({ 
  dest: uploadPath,
  fileFilter:  (req, file, callback) => {
  callback(null, imageMineTypes.includes(file.mimetype) )
 }
})
```

and this is the error that it's giving

```
(node:7447) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Input file is 
  missing
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify `dest` option in `multer()` it will save the file to that directory and you will have to pass that directory to `sharp()` like this

```
sharp(req.file.path)
```

Otherwise you can drop the `dest` option and pass the buffer to `sharp()`

```
sharp(req.file.buffer)

...

 multer({ 
  fileFilter:  (req, file, callback) => {
  callback(null, imageMineTypes.includes(file.mimetype) )
 }
```